# Will mounting a volume to a locations containing files of the same name overwrite those files or will they be used?

Tags: docker

I'm looking for some help. If I use `docker run` to run a container and I have used `-v` to mount to a volume that already has files contained (these files are the files from a previous run of the container but with a config file edited). Will the container I run then use the contents of the files I have overwritten or will it use the files within the container anyways and disregard the files I have edited? 
I am running
`sudo docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/opt/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet`

And in `/opt/stellar` on my machine (AWS EC2) I have files alredy there included an edited stellar-core.cfg file.

Sorry if this is the a bit confusing. I am trying to explain what I mean as best I can. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory ...
```

Then whatever is in the host directory will always hide whatever was in the image on that path, and if the application in the container makes changes in `/container/directory`, they will be reflected in the corresponding host directory.

If you update the image to have changes in the container directory, and you run the same `docker run` command, the host directory will still hide the image’s contents, and you won’t see those changes in the re-run container.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you are not talking about `volumes` but about `bind mounts`, unlike `volumes`, they allow you specify location on host machine.

The answer to your question is following:

1. Bind mount always uses **hosts** content. If container had something in mounted folder, it will be overriden.
2. Whenever you modify your folder from container, the changes persist on host (unless you bind ion readonly mode - then your changes would be rejected)